# Login Activity is not an enclosed class

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I am getting compile error in line `.addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this` : Login Activity is not an enclosed class.

Am I doing anything wrong in below code?

**Below is my code in Activity**

```
public class LoginFirebase extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    Button btn_Login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_firebase);
        btn_Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);

        btn_Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {                
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("username", "password")
                    .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        }
                    })

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace LoginActivity to LoginFirebase .